# find which image view was clicked

Tags: android, tags, onclicklistener

[image]i created a taglayout that makes dynamic tags with strings inside, similar to the tags of stackoverflow. so adding and deleting from the list is done by a button click = add, and an image click = delete. when i create a tag with the button i can delete it by pressed the "x" next to it without a problem. but when adding it to the list i dont know which image view was pressed so i can delete. i found out i cant get the id of the image that was pressed so any other ways?

```
 adding.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == adding) {

                    // Read the edit text
                    stuff = interest.getText().toString().trim();

                    // Inflate the tag layout
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.tagLayout);

                    final View tagView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_layout, root, false);
                    root.addView(tagView);
                    // Get access to the subviews of Tag View
                    final TextView tagTextView = (TextView) tagView.findViewById(R.id.tagTextView);
                    imgFavorite = (ImageView) tagView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


                    tagTextView.setText(stuff);

                    groupedInterests.add(stuff);


                    imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View b) {
                                    //remove the tag
                                    ((ViewGroup) tagView.getParent()).removeView(tagView);

                                  //FIND OUT  WHICH IMAGE VIEW WAS PRESSED SO I CAN REMOVE THE STRING FROM THE LIST 


                                }
                            });
                    Log.i(TAG, "first id given" + id);

                     id = id + 1;
                    interest.setText("");
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: If answer below doesn't help please try to explain more what you're problem is and maybe I can help better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the `stuff` string as a tag on the `tagView`.

```
tagView.setTag(stuff);
```

Then in the onClick you could get the tag

```
String textToRemove = (String) tagView.getTag();
// Remove string from list
```

Alternatively you should with your code be able to access `tagTextView` inside your `imgFavorite` click listener.

```
imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View b) {
            //remove the tag
            ((ViewGroup) tagView.getParent()).removeView(tagView);

            //FIND OUT  WHICH IMAGE VIEW WAS PRESSED SO I CAN REMOVE THE STRING FROM THE LIST
            String stringToRemove = tagTextView.getText();
        }
    });
```